# MySQL not allowing to create table

Tags: mysql

I'm learning about MySQL, I just made my first databank, but when I make a table called "pessoas", as shown in an Youtube tutorial, it showed these two atached error messages, and didn't let me see the table created. I've tried to put back accents surrounding the words, but didn't work. Can someone explain me what's going on?

[image]

Comment: please attach your query.

Answer (score 0):

A.A.,
your `CREATE TABLE` runs successfully on MariaDB 10.4.13.

The actual error messages are related to queries that retrieve information about database users, I guess these queries come from the MySQL Workbench itself.
My best guess is that your database and Workbench have different versions. Personally I am not a big fan of the Workbench (only for query profiling), so maybe try out another client: MySQL commandline, HeidiSQL, phpMyAdmin, ...

Best regards,
Martin

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Here is the code I wrote: create table pessoas (
id int not null auto_increment,
nome varchar(30) not null,
nascimento date,
sexo enum("M", "F"),
peso decimal(5,2),
altura decimal(3,2), 
nacionalidade varchar(20) default "Brasil",
primary key(id)
)default charset= utf8mb4;

Comment: I'm using mysql 8.0.18, I also tried it with MariaDB 10.4.10. I've installed database workbench, but I don't know how to use it yet

Answer (score 0):

Your SELECTa are gibberish for mysql that is why they fail

See you second select for example

```
SELECT 
    Db as scopeuserhostSelect_priv 
    AS Selectlnsert_priv 
    AS lnsertUpdate_priv 
    AS UpdateDelete_priv 
    AS DeleteCreate_priv 
    AS CreateDrop_priv 
    AS DropGrant_priv 
    AS GrantReferences_priv 
    AS Referenceslndex_priv 
    AS IndexAlter_priv 
    AS AlterCreate_View_priv 
    AS Create ViewShow_view_priv 
    AS Show viewTrigger_priv 
    AS TriggerDelete_versioning_rows_priv 
    AS Delete versioning rows 
FROM mysql.db 
WHERE cadastro2 likedb
```

A query looks something like this

```
SELECT `test12`.`id` as id,
    `test12`.`usr_id` as usr_id,
    `test12`.`category` as category,
    `test12`.`comp_id` as comp_id,
    `test12`.`position`as position,
    `test12`.`description` as description,
    `test12`.`country` as country,
    `test12`.`state` as state,
    `test12`.`city` as city,
    `test12`.`start_date` as start_date,
    `test12`.`end_date` end_date,
    `test12`.`timestamp` as timestamo
FROM `testdb`.`test12`
WHERE `category` LIKE 'tesmeifyou can';
```

every column is separated by comma, an alias for a column needs an actual column, and LIKE needs to compare a string

Here you find some more information on [SELECT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html)